# A constructor that takes two floats x and y as input, x is the real part, y is the imaginary part (Complex number). How would I set this up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class ComplexNumber:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x + self.y + "i"
```

I am trying to get a complex number. I am a total noob at coding and I am not sure what it's asking me exactly. But am I on the right path here?

Comment: `self.x` is not yet set, you need `x`. You probably want `self.c = x + y * 1j`, or `self.c = complex(x, y)`. Of course, you could also use `complex` directly.

Comment: What you've posted is an attribute error, because `self.x` and `self.y` were never set. Once you fix that I'd expect a type error, because `x` and `y` will presumably be numeric and Python is *strongly* typed, so you can't add them to a string. It's unclear what exactly your task is, but note Python does support imaginary numbers: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, python supports imaginary numbers. However, if you have to set it up manually for an assignment or something it could maybe look like this:

```
class ComplexNumber:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Basically you don't need the `i`, except maybe to display stuff, which you could do with additional class functions:

```
    def displayNumber(self):
        print(str(x) + " + i x " + str(y))
```

To really resemble complex numbers, you would also want to add functions that correctly handle complex numbers. For example:

```
    def addComplex(self, addX, addY):
        self.x = self.x + addX
        self.y = self.y + addY
```

This could be done with other functions as well, like multiplications, amplitude and so on. Even better would be to do this with operator overloading, but I guess this is out of the scope of this question.